# SQLAlchemy does not return all table names in SQL Server database

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

When I download this [example database, AdventureWorksLT2012_Data](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330), and try to access the table_names in sql alchemy, via

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://sa:PASSWORD_HERE@localhost:1433/AdventureWorksLT?driver=FreeTDS")
engine.table_names()
```

I get `['BuildVersion', 'ErrorLog']`. However this is missing tables from the database.

For example, executing this query gives the expected table names...

```
rs = engine.execute("SELECT name FROM sys.Tables")
[row['name'] for row in rs]
```

I get

```
['BuildVersion', 'Address', 'Customer', 'CustomerAddress', 'Product', 'ProductCategory', 'ProductDescription', 'ProductModel', 'ProductModelProductDescription', 'SalesOrderDetail', 'SalesOrderHeader', 'ErrorLog']
```

Is this a bug, or have I overlooked something? If I create a new database, and tables with identical names as above, then `engine.table_names()` works as expected.

Comment: @Parfait, the db wasn't corrupted, issue can be reproduced by downloading  from link. I didn't realize that `engine.table_names` might only look at a particular schema in the db.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the corresponding [database creation script](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/downloads/get/373779), the two tables you get from `engine.table_names()` are the ones that are created in the `[dbo]` schema. The others are created in the `[SalesLT]` schema.

So it appears that `engine.table_names()` is only listing tables for the default schema in effect at the time it is invoked, which in this case happens to be `[dbo]`.

Comment: Ah, that's it! Thanks for pointing to the database creation script--it's really useful. In case it's useful to anyone, I ended up listing the tables from the SalesLT schema using `engine.table_names(schema = "SalesLT")`.